# Split string in java giving some issues

Tags: java, split

```
public class llearning1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "is";
        String x = "what is good";
        String y[] = x.split(" ");

        for (String temp: y) {

            if (temp == text) {
                System.out.println("found");
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

expected : code should display "found"

but it is displaying "nothing"

Comment: In the name of all humans, don't use `==` to compare Strings.

Comment: "*gicing some issues*"? Did you mean, "giving some issues"?

Comment: we are reaching to 6 string compare question per day,lets make it 10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the String with `equals()` method not with `==` operator

`==` operator is used to compares the reference of the object.

change i`f (temp == text)` to `if (temp.equals(text))`

Answer (score 0):

String is Object and object equality checks with `.equals()` method.

so try:

```
if(temp.equals(text))
```

**==** operator is used for object reference comparison means two reference is pointing to the same object or not or primitive(int, double, ...) value comparison.